# How to access dynamo db from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want access the Data of Amazon Data server from Node.js on specific primary key value. The Data is Available in the form:

```
{
  "Count": 9862,
  "Items": [
    {
      "Admin": {
        "S": "false"
      },
      "UserId": {
        "S": "e9633477-978e-4956-ab34-cc4b8bbe4adf"
      },
      "Age": {
        "N": "76.24807963806055"
      },
      "Promoted": {
        "S": "true"
      },
      "UserName": {
        "S": "e9633477"
      },
      "Registered": {
        "S": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "Admin": {
        "S": "false"
      },
      "UserId": {
        "S": "acf3eff7-36d6-4c3f-81dd-76f3a8071bcf"
      },
      "Age": {
        "N": "64.79224276370684"
      },
      "Promoted": {
        "S": "true"
      },
      "UserName": {
        "S": "acf3eff7"
      },
      "Registered": {
        "S": "true"
      }
    },
```

Everytime when I am Making Request with the code:

```
app.get('/Mydetails/:tablename/:id', function(req, res){
console.log('Table is ' + req.params.tablename);


var element = {TableName: req.params.tablename, Key:{UserID:{"S": '"'+req.params.id+'"' }}};
 console.log('Id is "' + req.params.id + '"');
dynamodb.getItem(element, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error occurred: '+err);
    }else{
     console.log('succeed');
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

then it gives the following error:

```
**ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema.**
```

However I have tried this also-

```
var element = {TableName: req.params.tablename, Key:{UserId:{"S": +req.params.id}}};
```

Any Idea? Any  help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using  the + sign here `+req.params.id`? That would change the id to a number (in your second case) which your schema shows userId to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also pass the range key if it exists in the 'Key', for the parameters

example
it should be

```
Key:{'thePrimaryKey':{ "S": 'primaryKey' }, 'theRangeKey': {'S': 'rangeKey'} }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are sending a variable named **params** which I don't see where you populate it.

You should be sending **element**: *dynamodb.getItem(element, callback)*

Comment: yeah ,I have used dynamodb.getItem(element, function(err, data) this line as well but nothing happens,means same result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo (case difference) in your UserID (vs UserId). - Upper case D.
Give a try with this change.